# Print a variable Once in a Recursive Function, which keeps changing with each Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a `void` function in c++. It is recursive. During each recursion I pass on a vector that gets updated in the function. I want to print the vector only when it gets out of the function completely. But If I simply print the vector at the end of function, then it will be printed each time it gets out of recursion. Is there any condition I can apply so that I can make sure printing happens only once (At the end of the first function call)?

I really don't want to change the function return type from '`void`' to anything. Is there a way or is it impossible?

EDIT:
Code looks something like below

```
void myClass::shortestPath(string* ar, int dim[2], vector<vector < int > > & path, vector<int > & minPath) {
    if (condition) {
        #some code to update path and minPath
        shortestPath(ar,dim,path, minPath);
    }
    #I cannot print minPath here because it will print each time it returns
    return;

}
```

Comment: anything stopping from you sharing your code?

Comment: Print it where you define if the recursion should end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easies way would be creating second function:

```
void mainFunction(vector<...> &v) {
    prepareVector(v);
    printVector(v);
}

void prepareVector(vector<...> &v) {
    //your recursive code here
}
```

Second option is adding some parameter for determining if this is first call or not:

```
void recursiveFunction(vector<...> &v, bool first=true) {
    ...
    recursiveFunction(v, false);
    ...
    if(first) {
        printVector(v);
    }
}
```

In your code, if you just want to print it once, at the end, you can change your code to:

```
void myClass::shortestPath(string* ar, int dim[2], vector<vector < int > > & path, vector<int > & minPath) {
    if (condition) {
        #some code to update path and minPath
        shortestPath(ar,dim,path, minPath);
        return;
    }
    // now you can print it here we terminate calls before this line
    // if condition is true
    return;
}
```

I'm assuming, that following condition is satisfied: You are making recursive call if and only if `condition` is true.

But this function could me replaced with `loop`:

```
while(condition) {
    #some code to update path and minPath
}
```

Comment: In 2nd option, when you recursively call the function with second argument as false, won't the variable `first` be set to 'false'? (because the function receives second argument as variable `first`)

Comment: @DarshilChauhan Yes, that's the point: no prints from the recursive calls.

Comment: I was asking, In the first call, `first` is true. Then when you call the function recursively, `first` is set to false. And it stays that way throughout all the recursions. It never becomes true again. When function gets out of all the recursions (back to the first call) and reaches the `if` statement for printing, `first` would be false right?

Comment: No, it will be `true`. There is no reference to variable `first`, each recursive call has its own copy of it. So calling with changed value doesn't change value for current call.